# PHP code won't execute with specific variable

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
class FormValidator {

    private $firstname;
    private $lastname;
    private $email;
    private $fields_with_lengths = array('first' => 2, 'last' => 2);
    private $color = '<span style="color:#FF0000">';

    function checkFirst($firstname) { 
        $first_error = NULL;
        if(strlen(trim($firstname)) < $this->fields_with_lengths['first']){
            $first_error = $this->color . 'Please enter more than ' . $this->fields_with_lengths['first'] . ' characters.</span>';
        }
        return $first_error;
    }

    function checkLast($lastname) {
        $last_error = NULL;
        if(strlen(trim($lastname)) < $this->fields_with_lengths['last']){
            $last_error = $this->color . 'Please enter more than ' . $this->fields_with_lengths['last'] . ' characters.</span>';
        }
        return $last_error;     
    }



    function validateEmail($email){
        return preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $email);
    }


}
```

Here is where I call it:

```
$validator = new FormValidator();
                $firstResult = $validator->checkFirst($_POST['firstname']);
                $lastResult = $validator->checkLast($_POST['lastname']);
                $emailResult = $validator->validateEmail($_POST['emailaddress1']);

                if (is_null($firstResult) && is_null($lastResult) && $emailResult) {

                    $mail = new PHPMailer();

                    $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
                    $mail->AddAddress("s...@....com");

                    $mail->Subject  = "test";
                    $mail->MsgHTML($messageHTML);

                    redirectULS('english/forms/thankyou.php');

                    if(!$mail->Send()) {
                        echo 'Message was not sent.';
                        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    } else {

                        //$bridge->pushLead($lead);
                    }
                }
```

This only works if I remove $emailResult from the if statement.  What am I doing wrong.  I'll take into account the earlier comments about functions that only return true or false later.  Right now I need to fix this if statement.  Thanks.  (Some variables are set elsewhere.  All I want to know here is how to get the if statement to work.)

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens exactly? What errors do you get, if any?

Comment: I don't get any errors.  The code in the if statement doesn't execute with the $emailResult variable in it.  Even by itself.  If I remove it, the code in the curly braces executes.  It's just the one variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump($firstResult, $lastResult, $emailResult);
```

> preg_match() returns the number of
>   times pattern matches. That will be
>   either 0 times (no match) or 1 time
>   because preg_match() will stop
>   searching after the first match.
>   preg_match_all() on the contrary will
>   continue until it reaches the end of
>   subject. preg_match() returns FALSE if
>   an error occurred.

```
$email = "me@me.com";
echo preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $email); //1 (true)

$email = "me+me.com";
echo preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $email); //0 (this is not false)

$email = "me@me.com";
if(1 == 1 && 0 == 0 && preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $email)){
    echo "OK"; //yup
}
```

Comment: So I need to check and see if it equals 1, then?

Comment: @shummel7845: Which should already work because any number different from `1` evaluates to `true`. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: You can put != 0, but that is the same thing. echo / print $emailResult and then you will know for sure. This should work as it is, however.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with validateEmail function... try replacing is_null() with empty(). Who knows...

Answer (score 0):

preg_match returns the number of matches for the given pattern(either 1 or 0). You are evaluating in a very weird manner here. You may want to check that.

Comment: what would be a better way to evaluate?

Comment: if the result of preg_match is 1, you can return true, else false. Then you know whether a match has been made. As Webarto states above, it seems correct, but we can't be sure of the logic of your program. The if happens if a match is found right ?

Comment: also check what the posted value is and if it matches, it would be a good idea to print the result of preg_match

Comment: but the php evaluates the returned value for preg_match as true 1 or false 0, so it should not be happening.

Comment: yes, i said that above, but it all comes down to what he wants to evaluate with that returned value. That is why i propose dumping the value(to see if the pattern and email is ok) and then handle the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I did a test and your code works right.
Can you put the error message here?